# Understanding hex dump of a file generated by Java?

Tags: java, hex, hexdump

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");                      
file.createNewFile();                                  
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
outputStream.write(65);                                
outputStream.write(66);                                
outputStream.flush();                                  
outputStream.close();
```

When I open test.txt in a Text editor I will see

```
AB
```

which are the UTF-8 characters with values 65 and 66.

I take a hex dump of the file and I see:

```
File Owner:             koraytugay
Group Owner:            staff
File Size:              2 Bytes
File Creation Date:     2014-11-04 13:18:45 +0000
File Modification Date: 2014-11-04 13:19:01 +0000

HEX DUMP:
[]   41 42                                               AB
```

So what is [] 41 42 supposed to mean here? Why not 65 and 66?

Comment: A "hex dump" displays byte values in hexadecimal -- that's why it's called thus.

Answer (score 3):

The decimal number 65 *is* 41 hexadecimal.

The decimal number 66 *is* 42 hexadecimal.